Why can't I open the shared profile URL on my iPhone? It shows a 404 error."
Why does the shared profile link copied from my app work on desktop but not on my iPhone, where it shows a 404 error? In my computer Mac function perfectly, but when i want to share de "Perfil" whith my phone, doesnt function.
PerfilUsuario.jsx
if (user) {
  const url = `${window.location.origin}/perfil/${user.uid}/compartir`;
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(url);
  alert("¡Enlace copiado! Comparte este enlace: " + url);
  // Intenta copiar con navigator.clipboard.writeText()
  navigator.clipboard
    .writeText(url)
    .then(() => {
      alert("¡Enlace copiado! Comparte este enlace: " + url);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      // Método de respaldo usando document.execCommand()
      const textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
      textArea.value = url;
      document.body.appendChild(textArea);
      textArea.select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
      document.body.removeChild(textArea);
      alert("¡Enlace copiado! Comparte este enlace: " + url);
    });
}

};
https://github.com/clemesilva/Ameterle2.git
